# Get total price and quantity of items sold with price changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm, report

I have these tables:

- items ( pk:id | Name )
- priceChanges( pk:id | fk:item_id | price | fromDate | toDate )
- request( pk:id | deliveryDate)
- requested_category( pk:id | assigned_quantity | fk:item_id | fk:request_id )

The PriceChanges table keep track of the price's change of every item.
I want to get the items sold between two dates with the total income (price*quantity) for ech item, while the quantity is the total count of ths item sold with the same price in the period (without the item's price change).
That means that whenever the price for a change i get a new row with the total count of items sold with the new price.
Here is an exemple of the desired output :

```
id      Name      sold    price     total  
------  -------   -----   ------    ------
8P01    51645A    3       1,20      3,60  
8P01    51645A    1       2,82      2,82
8P01    51645A    5       2,50      12,50
```

i have tried this SQL command, but i can't stop getting too many duplicated row :

```
SELECT
i.id,  
i.name,
sum(rc.assigned_quantity) AS assigned_quantity,
pc.price,
pc.price * sum(rc.assigned_quantity) as total 
FROM requested_category rc 
LEFT JOIN items i ON rc.item_id = i.id 
LEFT JOIN request r ON rc.request_id = r.id 
LEFT JOIN priceChanges pc ON pc.item_id = i.id
WHERE
r.delivery_date BETWEEN 'startDate' AND 'endDate' 
GROUP BY i.id, i.name, pc.price
```

the result that i get:

```
id      Name      sold    price     total  
------  -------   -----   ------    ------
8P01    51645A    3       1,20      3,60  
8P01    51645A    1       1,20      1,20
8P01    51645A    5       1,20      6,00
8P01    51645A    3       2,82      7,86  
8P01    51645A    1       2,82      2,82
8P01    51645A    5       2,82      12,10
8P01    51645A    3       2,50      7,50  
8P01    51645A    1       2,50      2,50
8P01    51645A    5       2,50      12,50
```

I tried as requested in comments below the follow query:

```
SELECT i.id, i.name, rc.assigned_quantity, pc.price
FROM requested_category rc 
LEFT JOIN items i ON rc.item_id = i.id 
LEFT JOIN request r ON rc.request_id = r.id 
LEFT JOIN priceChanges pc ON pc.item_id = i.id 
WHERE r.delivery_date BETWEEN 'startDate' AND 'endDate'
```

I get this result:

```
 id     name   assigned_quantity    price
8P01    51645A 1                    1.20
8P01    51645A 1                    2.82 
8P01    51645A 1                    2.50 
8P01    51645A 3                    1.20 
8P01    51645A 3                    2.82 
8P01    51645A 3                    2.50 
8P01    51645A 5                    1.20 
8P01    51645A 5                    2.82 
8P01    51645A 5                    2.50
```

Thank you

Comment: can you post a sample of what you that query is returning pls?

Comment: Please indicate (add to your post) your Primary and Foreign keys.

Comment: Have you tried removing the LEFT JOIN and just doing standard JOINs?

Comment: (item_id,fromDate) seems like a decent PK to me

Comment: @LuisAlves  @ PM 77-1 I edited the question with detailed informations.   
@ Strawberry unfortanly, i don't have the hand to alter the DB structure.  
@ TheShaman I'll try the JOIN Statement ASAP and return the output.

Comment: Add the original table data pls Or just the return from the query: SELECT
i.id,  
i.name,
rc.assigned_quantity,
pc.price,
FROM requested_category rc 
LEFT JOIN items i ON rc.item_id = i.id 
LEFT JOIN request r ON rc.request_id = r.id 
LEFT JOIN priceChanges pc ON pc.item_id = i.id
WHERE
r.delivery_date BETWEEN 'startDate' AND 'endDate'

Comment: @luisAlves request result are added to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a select sum(quantity) and put in a group by and having clause? @inaliaghle

Comment: I created a table with the data from the last query you executed. Then I run the following query: SELECT id,  name, sum(assigned_quantity) AS ssigned_quantity, price, price * sum(assigned_quantity) as total 
FROM SOTEST GROUP BY id, name, price; and I got the result you expected. I think the error may be due to the joins (I'll keep investigating)

Comment: This is a bling shoot, but try the following query pls: SELECT i.id, i.name, sum(rc.assigned_quantity) AS assigned_quantity, pc.price, pc.price * sum(rc.assigned_quantity) as total 
FROM requested_category rc 
LEFT JOIN items i ON rc.item_id = i.id 
LEFT JOIN request r ON r.id = rc.request_id
LEFT JOIN priceChanges pc ON pc.item_id = rc.item_id
WHERE
r.delivery_date BETWEEN 'startDate' AND 'endDate' 
GROUP BY rc.item_id, i.name, pc.price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came back with the solution I used.
In my application, I use Symfony Framewok and Doctine Framework to handle the database.

i'm not a DBAdmin, but I think that this solution can be achieved by database triggers as well. In this case, I chose the applicatif approach because I used [Top-Down design](http://databasemanagement.wikia.com/wiki/Database_Design_Strategies).

The business logic behind the need is trying to get the store output reporting (items*price per period) knowing that the price is fixed at the item's importation time.

I used the [Entity Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html) that watches for any change in items price. Whenever there is a change, I log the (price, quantity, start date,end date)
And when the reported is generated, I simply match the period with items price change and multiply it with the quantity that is logged in the same database entry.

Hope I helped someone.